# SQLAlchemy: How to use an instance in SQLAlchemy after session.close()?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am having problems using an instance in SQLAlchemy after session.close().

This is the code:

```
session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
object = session.query(Entity).filter(Entity.id == id).one()
object.name = "Foo"
session.commit()
session.close()
print object.name
```

It throws a DetachedInstanceError.

I have tried to detach the object, expunge_all() and nothing.

Thanks

**Edit**

I found out what was the problem. For future reference I will answer my own question.

session.commit() sets the object instance as expired, when I try to access to the object attributes after the close() statement SQLAlchemy tries to refresh the instance.
Calling refresh after commit() solves the problem.

Comment: This can help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25694346/134904

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the setting `expire_on_commit=False` which affects the `commit` call and may mean you don't need to do the `refresh` (assuming that's costly).