# Python SQLAlchemy Error: Instance is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy Model:

```
class MyObject2(db.Model, Timestamp):
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), nullable=False, primary_key=True) 
    myobj1_id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), db.ForeignKey(MyObject1.id), nullable=False) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(25))

    def __init__(self, myobj1_id, name=None): 
        self.id = uuid.uuid4() 
        self.myobj1_id = myobj1_id
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, myobj1, name=None):
        try:
            myobj2 = cls(myobj1_id=myobj1.id, name=name)
            db.session.add(myobj2)
            db.session.commit()
            print myobj2     #<=========== LOOK AT THIS LINE!
            return myobj2
        except Exception:
            db.session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            db.session.close()
```

Notice that there is an extraneous print statement in there. 
See? It doesn't really do anything. Oh well.

Now, here is the code that calls the `create()` method to create an instance of the model:

```
myobj2 = MyObject2.create(myobj1=myobj1, name='Hello') 
serialized_myobj_2 = MyObject2Serializer(myobj2).data
```

All this works fine. But as soon as I remove the unnecessary print statement, I get the following error in the last line of the caller:

```
Instance <MyObject2 at 0x7ff804ac5710> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

Why? How does the absence of the print statement cause this bug?
When I googled around for this error, I found [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253978/sqlalchemy-get-object-not-bound-to-a-session?answertab=oldest#tab-top). But the solution given there -- to call `session.expunge_all() right before`session.close()` -- didn't work for me.

What's the solution to getting rid of that print statement without breaking my code?

Comment: Please include your `Session` configuration, if any. In its default configuration SQLAlchemy `Session` [expires all database loaded state on commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#committing). That's why the print matters; it causes an implicit refresh, before the session is closed for good. Having methods such as your `create()` handle the session's/transaction's lifetime is a bit of an antipattern: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it.

Comment: Iljia, there is no explicit session configuration. Here are the only two other methods of the `MyObject2` class that I omitted in my original post: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/5e093b6671d43b913c308a0a05b07fc6

Comment: Gravedigging, but putting `expunge_all()` before `close()` is too late. It is `commit()` (or `rollback()`) that expires the attributes. In fact `close()` implicitly expunges all objects, but since you have explicitly committed or rollbacked, the attrs are gone.